# How to work with more than one version of the same application at the same time in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I have an application that is going to be used for a lot of clients, currently we have two versions of it, one is the core version, the other will be used by one of my client. For now we have two branches (master, client_1) and they're similar, but different.

My problem is that if I correct something just for client_1, it's easy, I just have to commit in that branch. But if I correct something for both, I don't now how to "merge" it, because if I merge my git tries to merge everything, not just my correction.

Now, imagine that my application expands to 15 clients, each one has something different, small changes, but it's different. How do I control this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "cherry-pick". That small change, you commit it on the main branch... then on the client branch, you cherry-pick the revision.

Comment: So, when I cherry-pick, what changes am I commiting to my client branch?

Comment: You will only carry over the changes introduced on that revision. It's like applying a patch, so not even the files are brought over... only _changes_ between the revision you are cherry-picking and its parent are considered and brought over.

Comment: Cool, that looks like what I want, but I'm not used to this term "revision", is that something I should search for? Do you thing I can work this way for my application? even with a lot of clients?

Comment: A revision is what you create when you commit something. A new revision is created... and then if you are working on a branch, the branch _pointer_ is moved to this new revision. And sure... you _could_ work this way.... but I think it would be much better if you had a master branch with "code for release" and a development branch where you are testing stuff up. You could cherry-pick stuff to the master branch and then have all the client branches merge the master branch instead of cherry-picking the same revision 15 times. This is actually very "artistic". Different devs use different flows.

Comment: That looks great, but my application have some global variables that for each client it changes their value, so I can't have a executable master then, right? Even if I could work this out, wouldn't I need to merge 15 times to my other branches?

Comment: Right.... but at least you have a _common_ branch (and revision)... you will have to manage 15 separate revisions on 15 branches by cherry-picking on each one. Don't get me wrong: It's all technically possible... just not the best approach. But feel free to go that route if you like it.

Comment: I really don't want to use cherry-pick for all my branches, as you said, I want something consistent and fast, your approach seems correct, my only question now is, 1- You said that instead of cherry-picking the same revision 15 times, I should merge master, but how can I do this merging just one time? 2- Am I doing right using git or there's a better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I might be biased... but there's nothing out there that can beat git. Now, your explanation and your requirement about having to cherry-pick make it sound like you have a dev branch where you put stuff while it gets cooked... when you finally get something finished, you cherry-pick only that to the client's branches... it!s the same thing, but with a common branch for all the clients... so you keep dev, have a master where you will be doing the cherry-pick and then the client branches where you should be able to merge the master code.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, I just don't know how to merge from a master to all other branches. Btw, thanks a lot for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange it client-specific "cosmetics" changes should be done on the client-specific branch, or on fix branches branched from the client branch.

The philosophy is that these changes are never merged back onto the main branch.

In a perfect world all changes on the main branch should be safe to merge TO all client product branches, but you might want an additional test phase before accepting them.

If a change is made and checked in to the client branch that is wanted for main or specific other clients then `cherry-pick` is the way.

If an unwanted client edit is found on the main  then either you can roll main back, or apply another change to reverse it. Then cherry-pick it to where it should be if necessary.

Git cherry -v will show you what changes are available to be copied between the branches, while git cherry-pick will let you select a specific change set, or a number of related changes to merge over in isolation.

Note that your default regular flows should not involve cherry-picks, because the two instances of the change will have different hashes.

Comment: You're probably right, my master should always have just what my others branch will use. But the way I've implemented my master is kind of another client, maybe my master will even be my biggest branch... So do you recommend me to delete in my master what I won't use in others branches? Should I have a fix branch for each client branch?

Comment: Generally, it is up to users to go to a target and merge changes from a source, so how you name your branches, and how you and users use those names is pretty much up to you. It dies make sense that your main branch can be built as a viable "vanilla" product, but sometimes that is not possible, and vanilla just has to be another client.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I'm afraid I can't create a "viable vanilla", I'll learn how to use cherry-pick then. But should I have a "fix branch" for my client branches?

Comment: Depends how "branch happy" you are, how many engineers, etc. Some like 1 branch per defect. If you know the defect is for a specific client, branch from there, merge back there. If the engineer fixes something else in passing, check it in as a separate change, then it can be cherry-picked to main from the fix branch or the client branch.

Comment: Wow, that looks drastic! I would have a thousand branches, haha. So if I get it right, I would create a new branch for each defect (bug/correction to make)? After merging it back I would just delete that branch then, right?

Comment: Yes, you do have to cull the defect branches, but perhaps give it a little time incase there is an aftershock.

Comment: If you have previously had 1 branch per developer, then you have to consider 1 branch per developer+customer for these customer-specific fixes.